# Is there a word or phrase for a concert where one composer's works are played?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, music

Latvian has the word *autorkoncerts*, translated in the Latvian-English dictionary as *one composer's concert*. 
Russian has the phrase *авторский концерт*, which literally means 'author's concert'.

Is there an equivalent word or phrase in English for a concert during which the compositions of only one composer are played, parallel to the *solo recital* for vocal/instrumental performances?

<sup>(To be used on a poster alongside the Russian *Авторский концерт*.)</sup>

Comment: I'd just call it a *[one composer's name] concert*. But I see that Google Books has dozens of instances of [***single composer recitals***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22single+composer+recitals%22), which kinda suggests Anglophones don't have a single-word term for such things.

Answer (score 2):

A concert dedicated to a single composer is called an *all-[composer] concert* or *program(me)*:

> BSO Conductor Emeritus Bernard Haitink leads the final series of the 2017-18 season, an [*all-Brahms program*](https://www.bso.org/Performance/Detail/88669) featuring beloved pianist Emanuel Ax in the composer's monumental Piano Concerto No. 2.
>
> A unique collaboration between three star performers for an [*all-Beethoven programme*](http://www.euroarts.com/tv-license/1213-all-beethoven-concert). Concerto for Piano, Violin, Violoncello and Orchestra in C major.
>
> The Carthage College Chamber Orchestra presents an [*all-Beethoven concert*](https://www.carthage.edu/live/events/14305-chamber-orchestra-concert-all-beethoven) at 1:30 p.m. on Sunday, Nov. 8.
>
> From an [*all-Bach*](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=1017927) concert they gave last week at the Brooklyn Museum in New York, the members of the St. Luke's Chamber Ensemble perform the Trio Sonata in C minor, S. 526 …

This construction is not limited to composers:

> The Rivers Symphony Orchestra will be presenting a night of [*all-Baroque*](https://www.rivers.org/page/news-detail?pk=458378&fromId=162469) music from Handel, Telemann, Manfredini, Torelli and ...
>
> The 7th International Pharos Contemporary Music Festival opens on Friday 2 October 2015 with an [*all-percussion concert*](https://www.facebook.com/events/119313998417154/) by the renowned Dutch percussion group Slagwerk Den Haag (SDH).

Posters and other publicity might bill such concerts as *An Evening of [composer]*:

> The Southern Crescent Symphony Orchestra and the Clayton State University Orchestra present: [*An Evening of Brahms*](https://www.facebook.com/events/2035567490008191/) featuring …

A composer performing or directing a concert consisting only of his/her own compositions performs or directs a *concert of his/her own works*:

> Saint-Saëns had previously appeared at Wigmore Hall in a [*concert of his own works*](https://wigmore-hall.org.uk/whats-on/camille-saint-saens-orchestra-benoit-hollander-191006081500) with the cellist Joseph Hollmann in 1906.
>
> 12 January, Berlin (Hotel de Rome): Paderewski's first [*concert of his own works*](http://www.paderewski.muzykologia.uj.edu.pl/en_GB/ignacy-jan-paderewski/kalendarium).
>
> The concert marks not only [Brian] Tyler's London debut, but his first full-length [*concert of his own works*](https://www.billboard.com/articles/news/7256314/composer-brian-tyler-london-debut-philharmonia-orchestra).

Answer (score 0):

the **complete or partial collection of works**  [Uniform Titles for Music](https://books.google.com/books?id=Lbu7BHOiOukC&lpg=PA185&dq=%22single%20composer%22%20performance%20defined&pg=PA185#v=onepage&q=%22single%20composer%22%20performance%20defined&f=false)

As in:

> XYZ (name of performance in Russian): featuring a partial collection of
>   Rachmaninoff etc

Answer (score 0):

In French we say "concert monographique". It seems that you can also use this word in English. https://elenatarasova.ru/en/2012/11/04/eugenie-svetlanov-is-the-composer-concert-monograph/